How to configure Azure Function App to process Service Bus messages in parallel?
I have created an Azure Function App and created a function from a docker image in the Azure Container Registry.  The function is triggered by a new message being placed on an Azure Service Bus queue.
The host.json for configuring this function is copied below.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "05:00:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
      "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
          "autoComplete": true,
          "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
          "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
          "autoComplete": false,
          "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
          "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
          "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
      },
      "batchOptions": {
          "maxMessageCount": 1000,
          "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
          "autoComplete": true
      }
      }
  }    
}

Each execution of this function (triggered by a single message on the Service Bus queue) can take some time, sometimes up to an hour per execution.  I have noticed that, given the above configuration, my function does not auto-scale when a large number of messages are placed on the queue.  For example, if there are 100 messages placed on a queue at once, I would expect the total execution time to be about an hour or less.  Instead it takes about 100 hours, as each message is processed in series.
The function is nowhere near the maximum number of simultaneous instances allowed by this function app.
Is my function app configured correctly given my use case?  If not, could someone suggest how I could update it?
I have tried updating the configuration of the function app in a number of ways, all to no avail.  The Azure documentation around the semantics of each configuration value is not great and is hard to make sense of.
EDITED
Here is the function being used to process messages in the Function App
def main(msgIn: func.ServiceBusMessage):

    payload = msgIn.get_body().decode('utf-8')
    payload_json = json.loads(payload)
    # do things to payload_json
    # ...
    return

And here is the function.json used to point the above code to the correct Service Bus queue
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msgIn",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "isSessionsEnabled": true,
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queuename",
      "connection": "AzureServiceBusConnectionString",
    }
  ]
}

The queue queuename has sessions enabled.

It would help to see the function code, not just the configuration file. Otherwise there's no way to know if you're using sessions or not, batching messages or not. Next time, provide as much information as possible, just as if you were troubleshooting an issue yourself and ask for the details yourself.

You did not mention which price tier your function app is. In addition to Sean's points, increase maxConcurrentCalls , to the level that your function app instance can handle, rather than setting it to 1.

We're on Elastic Premium EP3.

Based on the provided configuration and subscription (pending validation as the function code wasn't shared at this point), I suspect you're processing messages individually, not as a batch and not as sessions. There are several issues with the configuration you've shared.

maxConcurrentCalls should be > 1. If set to 1, messages are processed serially when sessions and batches are not enabled.
maxAutoRenewDuration is set to 5 minutes 00:05:00. If processing is > 5 minutes, this value should be set to the maximum allowed time for the lock to be renewed.
prefetchCount set to 1. Prefetching drastically improves throughput. With a prefetch of a single message, you cannot take advantage of the performance improvements as a function has to wait for messages to be fetched rather than keep processing without wasting time on I/O waiting.


Thanks Sean.  I'm almost certain messages are being processed serially.  My concern with incrementing maxConcurrentCalls in messageHandlerOptions is that this causes multiple messages to be processed simultaneously by a single instance.  This slows down execution time for a single message considerably.
Ideally, messages would be processed in parallel, each being handled by a separate instance.  Do you have any idea about how to achieve this?

We're using the Function App service because of the possibility to have long-running jobs.  The auto-scaling behavior of Container Apps (with the ability to do exactly what I describe above via custom scale rules) would be ideal, but it does not seem possible to use Container Apps to process long-running jobs (60+ minutes long).  If we can't figure out how to achieve our goals with Function Apps, we could fall back on a custom Kubernetes cluster, but ideally, we would not have to do this.

It should be possible to do long-runnning professional with Container Apps because you're not limited in time. Assuming, you're extending the lock. Concurrent execution is not the same as parallel but why do you need to force new instances? New instances are spawned automatically based on the queue length

My understanding of Service Bus messages is that even when the lock is renewed by the holder, there is actually no guarantee that the lock is deterministically renewed from the perspective of the queue.  This creates an unfortunate situation where the same message can be simultaneously processed by multiple Container App instances.  I don't understand enough of the Service Bus implementation to know why this is.

Do you know how scaling based on queue length is handled?  How long does the queue have to be to trigger autoscaling?

Lock renewal is a client-side operation. That's why it's not guaranteed 100% to be successful all the time. This will be addressed in the future, when a necessary feature on the broker side will be enabled.  as for the queue length and scale out decision by Functions, that's an internal knowledge, not publicly available. Have a look into the Flex Consumption plan. It has the ability to scale per function.

@san-feldman in your first bullet point, I think you meant maxConcurrentCalls instead of messageHandlerOptions.

Indeed. Thank you

Thanks for your help.  I've come to the conclusion that Azure Function Apps are not the right tool for our use case.  To be honest, I'm coming away from this experience not really sure what the value of Azure Function Apps is.  They don't seem to add significant value over a VM+Load Balancer.
